# Which module can create a sitemap based on entity reference rather than menus?

Tags: views, 7, entities

Does a module exist that creates a sitemap based on entity reference rather than menus?

The site I am currently working on has it content linked using entity reference rather than using Drupal menus. The reason it has been done like this is because content can fall into multiple categories. But now I am facing the issue of generating a sitemap. Is there anyway to do this? Can it be done using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) maybe?

Comment: I don't think so, for situations like yours there is a taxonomy system and taxonomy-based sitemaps

Comment: Is there a way of adding links to the menu in bulk?

Comment: This site is not a forum. New questions should be asked as new questions. You can have as many as you want, so if you want to compare 3 ways, for example, simply ask 3 questions and see what answers you'll get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [XML Sitemap](https://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module, the main alternate to menu-based sitemaps, is the **XML Sitemap Node** submodule.

Enable the sub-module, then edit each content type.  There should be an **XML Sitemap** tab at the bottom of the form.  Set the inclusion and priority as needed.  An advantage of this, over using menu-based sitemaps, is that modified times will end up in sitemap.xml